# Facebook php : handling variables in redirect url

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, cakephp-3.0, facebook-php-sdk

so I know as of march Facebook changed stuff and I've read a lot of questions here, with the redirect url changes on how to handle parameters now, I haven't find a solution to my question, not saying it hasn't been asked though.

my redirect url goes like this :

```
https://mysite/app/calendar/delete/$id/
```

What it used to do : delete a scheduled post in my facebook page and from my calendar

Now : By setting my id in the controller, I manage to delete the scheduled post off the calendar, but not in my facebook page

There has to be a way to have the parameter accepted by facebook without having a "the redirect url isn't specified in app's urls" error, a solution I didn't find, but I honestly searched for it before posting, so sorry if you've seen that solution flying around.

Comment: Why would you need to transport that info in the redirect URI in the first place? The redirect URI is used for purposes of the login flow - why are you mixing the general process of login, with a very specific action to begin with? // If there is no danger that users will try to perform multiple such request “simultaneously” in different tabs, then you could simply put the id into the session, before you redirect to the login dialog.

Comment: Otherwise, your only option is to put it into the `state` parameter. (Since that originally serves CSRF purposes, you might not want to replace it with the id _only_ - a combination of a random value and your id would be the way to go, maybe encoded as JSON.)

Comment: @CBroe knew my question was confusing… I actually tried to explain, sorry about that, maybe I should make a more detailed question if I don't succeed, thanks, will try looking in that direction thoroughly, I've seen "state" parameters brought up, but couldn't find an example.

Comment: Well the PHP SDK handles generating and setting the `state` value itself, so you would have to check where to interfere with this process ... I think the relevant stuff is happening here, https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/e278500bfdfb1be0ea0ea73f58f36d78b6f5a98b/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L123 This checks if a state value is already set in the persistent data storage, and if not creates a new value there. So by using those same methods, you should be able to set a value yourself, before you call the method that creates the login URL.